# Do I need a subdomain or CNAME?

Tags: subdomain, apache2, cname

I have a domain with Godaddy (`mysite.com`) which is pointing to my AWS EC2 box.

Now I need a launchpad link on my website so that if the user clicks on it it would point to `launch.mysite.com`

This link should also point to the same AWS EC2 box and in there I would then capture the incoming host through Apache's  VirtualHosts and redirect it accordingly.

What confuses me most is now how to create the `launch.mysite.com` ?

Do I create a 'forward Subdomain' and forward it to my ip?  Or Do I create a CNAME pointing to the same ip?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CNAME` record is used to point to another hostname. For example, `sub.domain.com` can point to `my.other.site` and `my.other.site` would have an A-record to for example, `123.231.312.123`. `CNAME` and `A-records` are BOTH a type of subdomain. The only difference is how it's resolved.

The only benefit of using `CNAME` records, is that if you have a lot of subdomains pointing to one IP, you don't have to update them all manually if the IP changes, rather you update the record that the `CNAME` records point to.

`A-records` are marginally faster, because the system will connect directly to the end-server, rather than performing a lookup to resolve the `CNAME` to an IP.

Now in your case, if you already know how to use `VirtualHost` directives, and your DNS host supports it, you could point `*` to `IP-ADDRESS` which means, a wildcard subdomain `*.domain.com` pointing to either the hostname or the IP of your Amazon box. This would be very expandable in the future because if you have, for example, `launch2.example.com` it's already pointed to the Amazon box. (As are `monkey.example.com` and `sdg91nfadug.example.com`).

Or, you would just create a `CNAME` or `A-record` for just `launch.example.com` pointing to a hostname or IP respectively.